# load page depending a menu with zk

Tags: java, data-binding, zk

i have a zul page in zk, and i need refresh only the center with other page depending my menu.

My menu is a list in that i load from my database

`

```
    <borderlayout>
     //the header of my page
        <north>
            <html><![CDATA[
                   <h1> <b>My page</h1><h3>page 1</b></h3>
                   ]]></html> 

        </north>
        <west> 
    //Here I load a list that i consult from the database

            <div apply="org.zkoss.bind.BindComposer"
                viewModel="@id('vm')      @init('com.gemalto.segmentation.viewModel.MnoViewModel')">

                <listbox id="list" model="@bind(vm.mnos)" width="200px" rows="20">
                    <listhead>
                        <listheader label="Operators" sort="auto" />
                    </listhead>
                </listbox>

                <style>
                    div.z-listbox-body .z-listcell {
                    padding: 2px 5px;
                    }
                </style>
            </div>  


        </west> 

     //And here i need charge a page depending of the option of my list menu.
        <center> 
   .
   .
   .

        </center> 
    </borderlayout> 
</zk>`
```

my java class is:

`
    package com.gemalto.segmentation.viewModel;

```
import persistence.dao.MnoDAO;
import persistence.db.Mno;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.zkoss.bind.annotation.Command;
import org.zkoss.zul.Messagebox;

public class MnoViewModel {
    private Mno mno = new Mno();
    private boolean enabled;

    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public Mno getMno() {
        return mno;
    }

    public void setMno(Mno mno) {
        this.mno = mno;
    }

    public List<String> getMnos() {
        List<Mno> operator =  MnoDAO.getMnos();
        List<String> mnos = new ArrayList();
        for(Mno Lmnos : operator) {
            mnos.add(Lmnos.getMnoName());
        }
        return mnos;
    }
    @Command
    public void submit(){
        if(MnoDAO.getMnoByName(mno.getMnoName()) != null){
            Messagebox.show("Mno exist");
        }else{
            short a=0;
            if(isEnabled())
                a=1;

            mno = new Mno(mno.getMnoName(), mno.getTrigram(), mno.getPrefix(),     mno.getPrefixRequired(), mno.getProjectCode(), a);
            MnoDAO.createMno(mno);
            Messagebox.show("Mno created");
        }  
    }

    @Command
    public void delete(){
            Messagebox.show("deleted");

    }
}
```

`
And i do not know how can i convert my list in a menu that redirect to other page in my center page.

And i do not know how i can refresh only the center of my page

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create menu by using [Children Binding](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/MVVM/Data%20Binding/Children%20Binding).
2. To refresh only the center, you can append a include component inside center and change it's src attribute

   Or, you can do it by following steps:

   a. delete all center's children by: `center.getChildren().clear();`
      b. create center's children by: `Executions.createComponents`, refer to [Load ZUML in Java](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Composing/ZUML/Load_ZUML_in_Java#Create_from_URI)

Answer (score 0):

You can use include component in the center. This allow you to add pages dynamically only changing src attribute. You can insert a window, div or any component. Furthermore, you can use Executions.createComponents to create windows in the server side. Everything depends on the pattern you are using (MVVM or MVC). Comment us and we'll help you.

Regards

- [Example Executions.createComponents](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/composite/composite_component)
- [Example include](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Component_Reference/Essential_Components/Include)